# Get total monthly transaction from sub queries in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join

I'm having a challenge to get the monthly total sum of amount_tendered from both shop1 table and shop2 table, and the monthly total sum of payment_amount from payments table.
and if payments don't have a value for the month it should show zero.

```
shop1
--------------------------------------------------------
| trans_id  | amount_tendered  |     trans_date        |
--------------------------------------------------------
|   1       |    10.00         |  2020-09-03 06:09:55  |
|   2       |    15.00         |  2020-08-01 10:19:01  |
--------------------------------------------------------

shop2
--------------------------------------------------------
| trans_id  | amount_tendered  |     trans_date        |
--------------------------------------------------------
|   1       |    30.00         |  2020-09-01 16:09:55  |
|   2       |    15.00         |  2020-09-11 11:19:01  |
--------------------------------------------------------

Payments
------------------------------------------------------------
| payments_id  | payment_amount    |   payment_date        |
------------------------------------------------------------
|   1          |    100.00         |  2020-09-01 16:09:55  |
|   2          |    105.00         |  2020-09-11 11:19:01  |
------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT t1.yr, t1.mnth, ifnull(t2.total_trans,0),  ifnull(t3.payments,0) FROM
(SELECT YEAR(trans_date) as yr,
 MONTHNAME(trans_date) as mnth,
 FROM shop1
GROUP BY YEAR(trans_date), MONTHNAME(trans_date)
ORDER BY YEAR(trans_date), MONTHNAME(trans_date)) as  t1

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT( 
        (SUM(amount_tendered)  FROM shop1 GROUP BY YEAR(trans_date), MONTHNAME(trans_date)+
        (SUM(amount_tendered)  FROM shop2 GROUP BY YEAR(trans_date), MONTHNAME(trans_date)
        ) as 'total_trans'
)as t2
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT SUM(payment_amount )  FROM transactions GROUP BY YEAR(payment_date), MONTHNAME(payment_date) as payments
)as t3
```

The expected result

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|    yr      |    mnth    |   total_trans    |   payments  |
------------------------------------------------------------
|   2020     |   August   |    15.00         |    0.00     |
|   2020     |   September|    55.00         |  105.00     |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

> Error : Syntax error near 'FROM transactions GROUP BY YEAR(transaction_date), MONTHNAME(transaction_date) ' at line 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically compute the monthly sum in two separate subqueries, and then join the results.

I am not a fan of having one table per shop: having several tables with the same columns usually indicates a design problem. Here, we use `union all` to collect data from both tables before aggregating.

```
select t.*, p.payments
from (
    select year(trans_date) yr, monthname(trans_date) mnth, sum(amount_tendered) total_trans
    from (
        select trans_date, amount_tendered from shop1
        union all
        select trans_date, amount_tendered from shop2
    ) t
    group by year(trans_date), monthname(trans_date)
) t
left join (
    select year(payment_date) yr, monthname(payment_date) mnth, sum(payment_amount) payments
    from payments 
    group by year(payment_date), monthname(payment_date)
) p on p.yr = t.yr and p.mnth = t.mnth
```

The `left join` avoids filtering out months that have no transactions.